# Best solar cooker type for dim sunlight?

Tags: cooking, solar-thermal

The commercially available solar cookers seem to use a variety of different technologies. I have seen ones that use mirrors, ones that use evacuate tubes, and other things, in different configurations.

**I am wondering what combination of solar cooker features would be best at reliably boiling water in dim daylight conditions.**

Ideally I would be looking only at the subset of devices that cost <1000 USD and are marketed to individual consumers, or that are fairly easy for someone without special skills to assemble. If these constraints veer too closely into "shopping advice," please ignore them and I will be happy to delete them.

Thanks!

Comment: [GreatOutdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) might be another place to get an answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that.